# http authentication in background php/js

Tags: javascript, php, http, authentication

I have built a PHP site with embedded web-cam snapshots (reloads with JS every 2secs)

On my first cam I can login with url parameters e.g.: `cam1-url?usr=usr&pwd=pwd` and it works.

On my second cam I don't have a login option with url parameters so I must use: `usr:pwd@cam2-url` (http-authentication).

So, the `img/iframe` tag can't login on cam2 without showing the browser login frame when I load the site!

Are there are solutions for this problem?

Comment: i forgot, without use php:  fopen wrappers

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions here. Please be aware that we do not provide from-scratch coding service here. Please show us what you've tried already, how it failed and we might be able to help.

Comment: You picked the worst possible authentication method. Just search on how to use sessions and use those to authenticate users instead of URL parameters.

Comment: @aron9forever He probably didn't build or design the webcam...

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to use your server as proxy. Just make the `<img>` tag point to a PHP script that downloads the picture from the appropriate location. That will also allow to build a simple cache so you can serve your copy of the image rather than redirecting all concurrent users to the same camera.